# elegant way to add non-values to Map in java 8?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, guava

I am using immutable map

```
public Map<String,String> getMap(){
        return ImmutableMap.<String,String>builder()
                .put("FOO",getFooType())
                .put("BAR", getBarType())
                .build();
    }
```

In some cases, `getFooType()` or `getBarType()` would return null. That causes exception to be thrown from  `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap`. I am wondering if there is an elegant way to populate the map only with non-null and non-empty strings.

I am ok with any Map implementation, not confined to guava library.

I could do away with the following

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

String fooType = getFooType();
String barType = getBarType();

if (fooType!=null && fooType.length()>0){
    map.put("FOO", fooType);
}

if (barType!=null && barType.length()>0){
     map.put("BAR", barType);
}
```

Since I have many keys to be added to the map, this kind of if-checks make the code not pretty. I am wondering if there is any elegant way to do it.

I am using Java 8 for my project.

Comment: And these `getFooType` and `getBarType` are static methods?

Comment: What is the source of the items going into the map?

Comment: they are not static methods. items going to map are coming from method call. The method should return map

Comment: Do you need the map to be immutable? Is a `Collections.unmodifiableMap` also ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Optional` as the value of the map:

```
public Map<String,Optional<String>> getMap(){
  return ImmutableMap.<String,Optional<String>>builder()
    .put("FOO",Optional.<String>ofNullable(getFooType()))
    .put("BAR", Optional.<String>ofNullable(getBarType()))
    .build();
}
```

This way the map will store the optional objects wrapping your strings, and when you get values from the map, use `map.get(key).orElse(DEF_VALUE);` - this will give you the DEF_VALUE for the ones that have null values.

see more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Comment: good one. wondering if the `getMap()` can return `Map<String,String>` doing some post-processing on `Map<String, Optional<String>>`?

Comment: Take a look at `MapUtils` (dont remember if its guava or apacheCommons)- you can use filter to filter out the ones that the value is an empty optional, and then use convert to grt the values out of the remaining optionals. (But if you ask me, if its possible, leave it eith optionals)

Answer (score 4):

The repeated

```
if (fooType!=null) {
    map.put("FOO", fooType);
}
```

look verbose because, well, they are repeated. If you just put the conditional add operation into a method and reuse it, the code will look as compact as your initial non-conditional code as it consists of one method invocation per desired mapping.

Note that you can combine this with the Guava approach easily:

```
class MyBuilder<K,V> extends ImmutableMap.Builder<K,V> {
    public MyBuilder<K, V> putIfValueNotNull(K key, V value) {
        if(value!=null) super.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

…

```
public Map<String,String> getMap(){
    return new MyBuilder<String,String>()
            .putIfValueNotNull("FOO",getFooType())
            .putIfValueNotNull("BAR", getBarType())
            .build();
}
```

You can wrap the `MyBuilder` creation into a factory method of the `builder()` kind, if you prefer that coding style.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Java 8 solution:

```
public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return Stream.of(
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("FOO", getFooType()),
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("BAR", getBarType())
    )
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```